# E/launcher - Process exited with error code 135

Tags: node.js, selenium, protractor

I am trying to run the protractor test from my windows machine.

Configuration Used:

> OS : Windows 7
>
> Node : 6.11.3
>
> Protractor : 5.1.2
>
> NPM : 3.10.10

I am unable to run the Protractor test because of the below error.

```
C:\Users\Admin>protractor conf.js [14:45:16] I/launcher - Running 1 instances of WebDriver [14:45:16] I/hosted - Using the selenium server at http://localhost:4444/wd/hub [14:45:18] E/launcher - Error code: 135 [14:45:18] E/launcher - Error message: ECONNREFUSED connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0 .1:4444 [14:45:18] E/launcher - Error: ECONNREFUSED connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:4444
    at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_module s\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\http\index.js:238:15)
    at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
    at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:188:7)
    at Socket.socketErrorListener (_http_client.js:310:9)
    at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:188:7)
    at emitErrorNT (net.js:1277:8)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:80:11)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:104:9) From: Task: WebDriver.createSession()
    at Function.createSession (C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\p rotractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\webdriver.js:777:24)
    at Function.createSession (C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\p rotractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\chrome.js:709:29)
    at createDriver (C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\ node_modules\selenium-webdriver\index.js:167:33)
    at Builder.build (C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor \node_modules\selenium-webdriver\index.js:623:16)
    at Hosted.getNewDriver (C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\prot ractor\lib\driverProviders\driverProvider.ts:60:29)
    at Runner.createBrowser (C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\pro tractor\lib\runner.ts:225:39)
    at q.then.then (C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\l ib\runner.ts:391:27)
    at _fulfilled (C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\no de_modules\q\q.js:834:54)
    at self.promiseDispatch.done (C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_module s\protractor\node_modules\q\q.js:863:30)
    at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_ modules\protractor\node_modules\q\q.js:796:13) [14:45:18]
***E/launcher - Process exited with error code 135***
```

I keep receiving the error "E/launcher - Process exited with error code 135" noted in the stack-trace above.  How can I get the protractor test to complete successfully?

Comment: did you run Selenium server? If not then you should run it using `webdriver-manager start`. If it is not installed use `npm install -g webdriver-manager`.

Comment: Thank you very much for given a reply -- Yeah i tried then i got the error sir.

Comment: Thank you for reply my question -- Yeah, i tried but i got the error sir.

C:\Users\Admin>webdriver-manager start
webdriver-manager: using global installed version 12.0.6
C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_mo
dules\webdriver-manager\selenium\selenium-server-standalone-3.5.3.jar -port 4444

[16:12:03] I/start - seleniumProcess.pid: undefined
[16:12:03] W/start - Selenium Standalone server encountered an error: Error: spa
wn cmd ENOENT

Comment: Try with admin rights in terminal and see if it helps?

Comment: Yeah,i had done all of the stuff through Admin only Sir.

Comment: This could happen either because of an antivirus, firewall or something already running on port 4444

Comment: I followed what you suggested yesterday those are it's not running another one on port no 4444,i checked with Firefall status-off and i am also started the webdriver-manager start without antivirus apps also then also i got the same error is :: [15:48:25] I/start - seleniumProcess.pid: undefined
[15:48:25] W/start - Selenium Standalone server encountered an error: Error: spa
wn cmd ENOENT

Answer (score 9):

Try doing below steps:-

Open cmd and in the home path use below commands.

```
webdriver-manager clean
webdriver-manager status
webdriver-manager update
webdriver-manager start.
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks like You can't connect to the selenium server. Comment this :

```
seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub'
```

and replace it with:

```
directConnect: true,
```

just to check if is working directly. 
Also You can navigate directly to http://localhost:4444/wd/hub to see If you can  access there. If not it might be some firewall or something similar.

Comment: It's an alternate solution. But it may cause chrome driver version issue. @sanja-paskova

Answer (score 1):

First, open a command prompt and then 
run the following command:

`webdriver-manager start`

Open a second command prompt then enter your command. Mine is `protractor conf.js`

Answer (score 0):

Probably a bit late but I get this error when I fail to start server for web-driver using:

webdriver-manager start

Answer (score 0):

Update the chrome driver using the command =>
webdriver-manager update --versions.chrome <73.0.3683.68>

after upgrading just install node modules once again using cmd => npm install